# Replacing column values based on row location

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following `df`:

```
Vertex E1 E2 E3 E4
1      2  4
2      1  3  4  2
3      2  4
4      1  4  3  2
```

I want to replace all the elements in columns [E1:E4] with the value equal to its corresponding Vertex (with 0).

`df_output` is:

```
Vertex E1 E2 E3 E4
1      2  4
2      1  3  4  0
3      2  4
4      1  0  3  2
```

E4 of Vertex 2 was replaced with 0 as the value was equal to it's Vertex number i.e 2. Similarly E2 of Vertex 4 was replaced with 0 as it was equal to 4.

I can obviously solve this by iteration. But what is the Pandorable way of solving this?

**Extra Info:**
The above procedure is to remove self-loops if df corresponds to the adjacency matrix of a graph.

```
Vertex E1 E2 E3
1      2  4
2      1  3  4
3      2  4
4      1  2  3
```

(This represents [adjacency list/matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list))

I "merge" two vertices together, say vertex 2 & 4, and end up with:

```
Vertex E1 E2 E3
1      4  4
3      4  4
4      1  4  3
```

How I obtained it is by dropping the row with vertex 2 and replacing all the places with edge to vertex 2 with 4.

Now I need to remove self-loops such that:

```
Vertex E1 E2 E3
1      4  4
3      4  4
4      1  0  3
```

as the vertex 4 had an edge to itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eq(,axis=0)` to get logical data frame to locate positions where values should be `0` and then assign `0` to the corresponding cells:

```
df.set_index('Vertex', inplace=True)
df[df.eq(df.index.to_series(), axis = 0)] = 0
df.reset_index()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using [DF.loc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) should do the trick:

```
import pandas as pd

index = [0,1,2,3]
E1 = [2,1,2,1]
E2 = [1,1,2,3]
D = {'E1':E1,'E2':E2}

DF = pd.DataFrame(data = D, index = index)
DF.loc[DF.index == DF['E1'], ['E1']] = 0
DF.loc[DF.index == DF['E2'], ['E2']] = 0
print (DF)
```

returns

```
  E1  E2
0   2   1
1   0   0
2   0   0
3   1   0
```